# How to type Telugu in LaTeX and genrate PDF using MiKTeX

Tags: texniccenter, texlipse, indic

So far I have been using LaTeX for writing English documents. My favourite editor is TeXlipse in Eclipse. I am also comfortable with TeXnicCenter. My operating system is Windows. But now my intention is to write some short stories in Telugu. I want to write in my fav word processing tool LaTeX. How can do that? Please suggest me with some basic example. It will be great appreciation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: thanks..I will follow the rules. Happy to join the club..:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need an OpenType or TrueType font which supprts that language, eg Code2000. Then
the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Code2000}
\begin{document}

తెలుగు

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to run the example with `xelatex` or alternatively with `lualatex`; both are installed with every TeX distribution.
Code2000 is available from http://www.fonts2u.com/search.html?q=Code2000

Comment: You should add that this needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX.

Comment: getting expl2.sty error..how to overcome that?

Comment: update your TeX distribution

Answer (score 6):

This is what I get compiling the following file with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Pothana2000}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{telugu}

\begin{document}

చేయి అనగా మానవులు, చింపాంజీలు, కోతులు మరియు లెమూర్లకు గల శరీరభాగమునకు వేళ్లు
కలబాహ్యంగము. కోలా చేతికి ఎదురెదురుగా వున్న రెండు బొటనవ్రేళ్లు వుంటాయి కాబట్టి దాని శరీరభాగాన్ని
కూడా చేయి లేక 'పా'లు అంటారు.

\end{document}
```

(The text is what is taken from the main page of Telugu Wikipedia.) How to activate using XeLaTeX with TeXlipse or TeXnicCenter should be looked at in their manuals. But I wouldn't recommend the latter editor as it has Unicode support only in the most recent beta version. A UTF-8 capable editor *must* be used.

[image]

Comment: TeXnicCenter doesn't support Unicode (at least the stable release doesn't, I'm not sure about 2 alpha 4), and I assume these characters require Unicode.

Comment: [This page](http://www.texniccenter.org/news/152-texniccenter-20-alpha-4) says that the default for TC2-alpha4 is UTF-8. Surely previous version of TC2 had a partial support for Unicode.

Comment: getting expl2.sty error..how to overcome that?

Comment: @user13143 You need to update MiKTeX to version 2.9 or install TeX Live 2011 as your TeX distribution.

Comment: This is great. Both @herbert and egreg. Do you people know telugu? I hope no. That is why this is awesome.

Comment: @HarishKumar No, I don't know Telugu. But I know it's supported by Polyglossia and I simply went to http://te.wikipedia.org for finding a sentence in that language. The rest boils down to installing a font with Telugu characters and run XeLaTeX. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\tel}[Script=Telugu]{Pothana2000}
```

These are the two commands enough to write Telugu text in LaTeX.
wherever you want to write the Telugu text just type the following

```
{\tel insert any Telugu text here}
```

Note:- Run your LaTeX file by using the compiler as XeLaTeX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet compilable and add an screenshot of your result to your answer ...